# NVidia 7600GT periodically hangs

Tags: windows, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an issue with NVIDIA 7600GT video card on Windows7. Periodically it behaves strangely. In 3d games in has some strange artifacts and extremely low FPS (0-2) instead of 15-25. If I disable and enable it again in Device Manager, then it works fine. But after some time(I didn't found regularity), it again hungs. I tried a couple of video drivers, but the result is the same. And I tested it on two different computers with the same video card and an issue still reproduces.

Does it mean that video card is almost dead?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that your card is a problem, not drivers (you might try really old ones, just for testing purpose) or other hardware (tested on more PCs)
I had similar lags on 8800 GT and slowly it started to in all 3D apps, so I lowered its 3D clocks from about 600 to 500 and it solved my problem. You can do it on boot (http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Video-Tweak/MSI-Afterburner.shtml) or make those changes permanent (http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Video-Tweak/NVIDIA-BIOS-Editor.shtml)
You might also try to change thermal paste http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYpDLNscPIw

Comment: I will try to reduce 3D clocks. Thanks :)

Comment: Дай мне знать если сработает.

Comment: I tried with reducing GPU speed, but no result. I reduced GPU from 560 to 300, and memory speed to 400. I tried to use some 2D game, it worked but a bit slowly because of reducing GPU. Then I closed it, used some usual software, and 30 minutes later, I tried to run it again, and there were a lot of artifacts and extremely low FPS(1-2).

Comment: It's possible that your video adapter is simply (and slowly) dying.
It happens with all kinds of hardware, so just accept this fact.
My last suggestion would be attempting one of the most risky "repair" operations for video adapters: try to bake your 7600GT
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmzGnjJNZrM
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_taI-CkPD3M

P.S. This is very risky as I said before. There are as much success stories as fail cases. Please think twice before doing it.

Comment: Yeah, probably you are right, video adapter is dying and I need to change it. Thanks :)